# Finding symbols in Lean

Tags: lean, tutorials

There was already a question here of this type but I would like to ask more generally:

If I see some strange unicode symbols being used in Lean, is there a recommended way to find out how to type them, and finding out what they mean, other than asking here at Proof Assistants or at the Zulip chat?

**Is the best source the old [Lean 2 Quick Reference](https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/quickref.pdf) from 2017?**

Comment: +1. But I edited the last sentence to be emphasized in a different way, since the way you emphasized it is generally used for quotes, which doesn't seem to be what you were trying to do here. Also, would you be able to provide a hyperlink to the other question to which you referred here? I can guess which one it was, but it would probably be better if you do it!

Comment: How to type them is mostly user/editor-specific; vscode and emacs are both highly customizable. But, how Lean recognizes unicode characters is all about Lean. It should be documented somewhere. Lean 2 was pretty well documented, I'm not sure about Lean 3 but I haven't looked recently. Lean 4 has a highly sophisticated macro system (with evolving lacunary documentation). With some mild to serious effort you can teach Lean 4 to interpret any symbol any way you want within a specific context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unicode character input is an editor feature, so this answer is specific to VSCode.

If you have a Lean file open in VSCode, you can hover over a unicode symbol to see what input commands are available. E.g., if you paste the character • and put your cursor over it, you get the tooltip `Type • using \smul or \bub or \bu`. This works whether or not the character is used in syntactically correct form.

You can see a list of all the supported input abbreviations in the [VSCode plugin](https://github.com/leanprover/vscode-lean/blob/master/src/abbreviation/abbreviations.json).

Comment: In some ways, the official recommendation is that `abbreviations.json` file; it's copied over to all other editors.

Comment: Hmm I'll post it as a separate question you can answer, @It'sNotALie.

Comment: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/237/65

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Emacs, then the corresponding command is `C-u C-x =`.  This displays a buffer with lots of information about the character under point, including its Unicode name and `to input:` which shows you how to type it in the current input-mode.

Comment: I can never remember that command, so I usually do `M-x desc-ch` (for `describe-char`).